# Why we are passing function arguments to $scope.$apply

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

When I start to read about $digest and $apply and I clearly understand the both.

But I croosed the below code when I started to explore about $apply

```
$scope.$apply(function(){
     $scope.isLoggedIn = true;
});
```

What is the need of passing function arguments in $scope.$apply functionality.?Any ways $scope.$apply gonna call $rootscope.$digest and it gonna trigger all the watchers and value is going to update to the view. So why we are passing function arguments in $apply function.

Comment: So, were any of these answers helpful or do you need more details..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you already know [when to use `$scope.$apply`](http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html), look at this pseudocode from the [`$apply` docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply):

```
function $apply(expr) {
  try {
    return $eval(expr);
  } catch (e) {
    $exceptionHandler(e);
  } finally {
    $root.$digest();
  }
}
```

If you pass a function to `$apply`, then it is simply forwarded on to [`$eval`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$eval).

The docs for eval show that we can either pass a string or a function.

> - `string`: execute using the rules as defined in [expression](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression).
> - `function(scope)`: execute the function with the current scope parameter.

In your case, you are passing a function. The function is simply evaluated with the current scope as the first parameter.

```
$scope.$apply(function(scope) {
  scope === $scope;
});
```

So, in short: `$apply` can be called with a function parameter that will be safely evaluated before the scope digest begins.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're asking when we would want to use`$scope.$apply`. It is critical when integrating values outside of Angular. For example:

```
$scope.$apply(function(scope) { 
  var aValue = 'shemp'; 
  $scope.valueOnScope = aValue; 
});
```

Here's aValue that is not at all a part of AngularJs can now be added by the framework. You'll do this with values from game libraries like *phaser* or visual libraries like *D3*, but usually for constants that will stick around because $apply will only update the values once, unless you deliberately put it inside some kind of loop or, more commonly, an event handler.

$apply can be a fine tool for forcing a full $digest run and you'll find many developers using it for that purpose. If you want AngularJs to update a value outside of the framework whenever it changes then you better put a $watch on it followed by an $apply.

It's true that $apply will run the $digest on *all of the watchers* in your angular program, so to optimize your code you may want to use $apply sparingly.

Answer (score -1):

The code you shown is weird. It makes no sense, as $digest will be called without $scope.$apply.

$scope.$apply should be called if you are doing something what is outside of Angular.

Comment: It may not be *necessary* to call the code in this manner, but it is valid, and isn't particularly weird....

Comment: It's perfectly normal code. Maybe it's in a directive that listens to an element's event? Then it has access to $scope and also needs to call $apply(), since the event handler doesn't run inside the angular loop, and $digest will _not_ be called.